# Paired comparison for big data

Tags: experiment-design, paired-data

I want to measure the subject's response to 30 stimulus. I'm thinking of paired comparison, but this experiment will be impossible to perform (need C(30,2)=435 comparison steps). The reason of using paired comparison is its accuracy (as opposed to simply ranking)

What are my other alternative options? Can I sample the comparison space, and interpolate it?

Comment: Normally the binomial coefficient would be written with the arguments in the other order. See the last line of the introductory section (just before the 'Contents' section) [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I've changed it. But can you help me with the main question?

Comment: There's simply not enough explanation in the question for me to clearly understand what you really want to find out.

Comment: The gist is: How to use Pairwise Comprarison on 30 variables?

Comment: The same general way you would on three variables, but I suspect that if you are trying to do a pairwise on 30 variables, you probably want to answer a different question. You may be better to explain the underlying issue you want to find out about rather than the particular technique you think solves the problem. In any case, I'm probably not the best person to explain pairwise comparisons of many groups.

Comment: Are you simply trying to compare all pairwise combinations of stimuli?  Or are you trying to compare 30 stimuli simultaneously to another 30 measurements on the same subject or some expected values of the measurements?